# Почему у меня псевдоэлементы не отображаются?

Tags: html, css, scss

```
&__title {
        position: relative;

        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        font-feature-settings: 'clig' off, 'liga' off;
        font-size: 48px;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 60px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;

        &::before {
            content: '';

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            display: block;

            width: 126.677px;
            height: 131.955px;
            transform: rotate(-120deg);

            background: url(/images/icons/leaf2.png) no-repeat;
        }
    }
```

Если в devTools-е посмотреть видно, но он почему-то не отображается. Если написать текст в content, текст отобразится.

Comment: Проверьте путь к изображению, которое устанавливается в качестве фона псевдоэлемента.

Answer (score 0):

Я не особо знаю CSS, но попробуй

```
&__title {
    position: relative;

    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-feature-settings: 'clig' off, 'liga' off;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
&::before {
        content: '';

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        display: block;

        width: 126.677px;
        height: 131.955px;
        transform: rotate(-120deg);

        background: url(/images/icons/leaf2.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: У него написано всё тоже самое, только он использует препроцессор scss. Но за попытку красавчик, приятно видеть твои старания, не сдавайся:)

Answer (score 0):

У тебя всё работает, проблема в пути картинки. Чтобы проверить это, можешь вместо фоновой картинки закрасить весь псевдоэлемент в один цвет (через background-color) и сразу же его увидишь.

Ещё как вариант, можешь зайти в devtools и попробовать открыть фон по ссылке (правой кнопкой по ссылке и выбрать "open in new tab"). Если картинки по такому пути нет, то выдаст "Cannot GET" на странице, а если есть, то покажет картинку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Можешь почитать тут про ссылки](https://thecode.media/path/)